# Is there anyway to include less for Bootstrap via CDN?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to frame a question in Plunker by porting over some of my project's code... The thing is I've  written all of the styling in `less` as opposed to plain `css`. Is there anyway to get Plunker or any Internet code editor for that matter to import the bootstrap `.less` styling files via CDN?

Already have the below without a problem:

```
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.7.4/less.min.js"></script>
```

Cheers

Comment: I have not seen any CDN providing Boostrap Less sources. And this is expected considering it's about 70 files your clients will have to download and compile... Not a good idea.

Comment: you can import Boostrap styles with `@import (less) url()` which enable you to reuse the code by extending (see http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature), but does not allow you to reuse Bootstrap's mixins, see: http://plnkr.co/edit/rbK8CJmnyioFo2rb37dS

Comment: You shouldn't use less.min.js in production. Precompile the Less to CSS on the server side instead, and then serve the CSS as a static asset.